# Getting data from a specific function in .bat to C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

I have a `.bat` file on a public server, which has several functions in it

```
GET_LIST_OF_EMPLOYEES
//code
end

SOME_FUNCTION1
//code
end

SOME_FUNCTION2
//code
end
```

I try to get the output of the GET_LIST_OF_EMPLOYEES function into my C# app.

Is there a way, to get only the output of the GET_LIST_OF_EMPLOYEES function or do I have to get the whole output of the `.bat` file and customize it in my C# app?

Comment: "do I have to get the whole output of the .bat file" <- yes, unless it has parameters that allow it to behave in a flexible way, but it does not sound like that's the case.

Comment: @PeterB Hello Peter, thank you for your answer. Could you provide more information about these "parameters" that you are mentioning? Gonna have to study a bit more about .bat files now I guess

Comment: .bat files do not have functions. If you have a particular batch file and you are running it for some reason from C#, (which should itself be capable of doing whatever the batch file does), then [Edit] your question to include the content of the batch file, the C# command/code, and an explanation of what exact output you want to capture.

Comment: What does the bat file do you couldn't do in c# without the use of the bat file but more control?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most practical solution is just using a temporary file.
Your batch can output a file and, on your C# application you can be subscribed to changes in files in the temporary folder, for example, using FileSystemWatcher:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed?view=net-7.0

Comment: Links outside of SO are not reliable. MS often changes those pages and they won't be available in the future. Could you please provide a coding example within your answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).